# Terminal Not Working on 16.04 After Default Language Change

Tags: 16.04, command-line, gnome-terminal, language-support

I just used the command below to change the default language on my calendar

`sudo localectl set-locale LC_TIME=en_US.utf8`

After reboot, terminal is not working, let alone starting. I've tried using `gnome-terminal` and it's not helping.

Comment: Please elaborate! Your problem description is hard to interpret!

Comment: I can't get my terminal to open, it happened immediately after changing the default language, I'm assuming the change might have something to so with

Comment: I suspect that it's unrelated to that locale change. Try to recall other things you did before rebooting.